# I can't insert data from php to mysql

Tags: php, mysql

In my Mysql I have this table. And I want to send data
Id is autoincrement

| Id | insertId | invoceTaxApplayId | sumOfDist |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  |  |  |  |

```
 if (isset($_POST['basic'])) {
        $user_string = $_POST['basic'];
        $basic = json_decode($user_string); 
        foreach ($basic as $key => $value){
            $sql2 = "INSERT INTO `insert_tax_applay_map`( `insertId`, `invoceTaxApplayId`, `sumOfDist`) VALUES ('$value','', 5)";
            echo $sql2; //printed
            echo $key;
        }
        exit();
    }
```

I can see echos, but data isn't sent to mysql.

Comment: echo $key or $value also is working

Comment: you only created an sql string but you haven't executed any sql command.

Comment: Two upvotes for an obvious silly mistake? Smells fishy to me

Comment: Please read about **[SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)**. Instead of building queries with string concatenation, use **[prepared statements](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php)** with **[bound parameters](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php)**. See **[this page](https://phptherightway.com/#databases)** and **[this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)** for some good examples.

Comment: Tip: Don't declare SQL statements as variables, only use them as arguments to things like `prepare()` so you don't have a dud like this that doesn't execute. The code you have here is the same as `$sql = "lol"`, it doesn't do anything.

Comment: If you're just getting started with PHP and want to build applications, I'd strongly recommend looking at various [development frameworks](https://www.cloudways.com/blog/best-php-frameworks/) to see if you can find one that fits your style and needs. They come in various flavors from lightweight like [Fat-Free Framework](https://fatfreeframework.com/) to far more comprehensive like [Laravel](https://laravel.com/). These give you concrete examples to work from and guidance on how to write your code and organize your project's files as well as standards for defining and executing queries.

Comment: @JohnConde Nothing wrong with learning or making silly mistakes.

Comment: @tadman Than u so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fix the issue of not executing and your serious SQL injection bug with one simple trick: Prepared statements with placeholder values!

```php
if (isset($_POST['basic'])) {
  $user_string = $_POST['basic'];
  $basic = json_decode($user_string); 

  // Prepare your database query with placeholder values
  $stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO insert_tax_applay_map (insertId, invoceTaxApplayId, sumOfDist) VALUES (:insertId, :invoiceTaxApplayId, :sumOfDist)");

  // For each entry...
  foreach ($basic as $key => $value) {
    // ...execute the statement with that particular set of values.
    $stmt-execute([
      'insertId' => $value,
      'invoiceTaxApplayId' => '',
      'sumOfDist' => 5
    ]);
  }

  exit();
}
```

This example uses [PDO](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) but can easily be adapted to `mysqli` or whatever you're using.

> Tip: For general guidance on PHP, see [PHP the Right Way](https://phptherightway.com) for more resources.